# Dojo Chart to PDF conversion in IE11

Tags: charts, dojo, jspdf, html2canvas

**[PDF Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCxVv.png)**

I am new to DOJO charts and in one of the requirement, we have to convert Dojo Chart to PDF.

To achieve this we have used "JSPDF" and "html2canvas" libraries.

It is working fine in Google Chrome and not in IE11.

Kindly suggest.

Regards,
Byreddy

Here is my code....

PDF Test

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.charting.widget.Chart" id="chart1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; background-color:white;"></div>

<div id="chart1SelectableLegend"></div>

<button id="pdfButton" onclick="convertPDF()">DownloadPDF</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug:true, async:true"></script>

<script>

    require(["dojox/charting/Chart",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
"dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedColumns",
 "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
  "dojo/ready",
  "dojox/charting/widget/SelectableLegend", "dojox/gfx/utils",
    ],
   function (Chart, Lines, Default, StackedColumns, Tooltip, ready, SelectableLegend, Utils) {
       var chart1 = new Chart("chart1");
       chart1.title = "stacked chart";
       chart1.addPlot("stackedColumnsPlot", {
           type: StackedColumns,
           gap: 6,
           lines: true,
           areas: true,
           markers: true,
           labels: true,
           labelStyle: "inside",              
           tension: "2"
       });
       chart1.addAxis("x", {
           dropLabels: false,
           labelSizeChange: true,
           rotation: -20,
           majorTicks: true,
           majorTickStep: 1,
           minorTicks: false,
           font: "normal normal bold 12px Tahoma",
           fontColor: "black",
           labels: [{ "value": 1, "text": "A" }, { "value": 2, "text": "B" }, { "value": 3, "text": "C" }, { "value": 4, "text": "D" }, { "value": 5, "text": "E" }, { "value": 6, "text": "F" }]
       });
       chart1.addAxis("y", {
           title: "Cost",
           fixLower: "major",
           fixUpper: "major",
           includeZero: true,
           majorTickStep: 500,
           max: 1500,               
           vertical: true
       });

       chart1.addSeries("AC", [300, 500, 500, 600, 300, 280],
        {
            plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
            stroke: {
                color: "#FFFFFF",
            },
            fill: "#FFAEAE "
        });
       chart1.addSeries("TV", [244, 301, 699, 620, 820, 837], {
           plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
           stroke: {
               color: "#FFFFFF"
           },
           fill: "#FFEC94"
       });
       chart1.addSeries("ACCE", [500, 100, 100, 100, 200, 250], {
           plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
           stroke: {
               color: "#FFFFFF"
           },
           fill: "#B4D8E7"
       });
       chart1.addSeries("OTHER", [100, 150, 100, 700, 700, 0, 800, 300, 300], {
           plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
           stroke: {
               color: "#FFFFFF"
           },
           fill: "#56BAEC"
       });

       chart1.render();

       new SelectableLegend({
           chart: chart1,
           horizontal: true,
           align: top
       }, "chart1SelectableLegend");          
   });
</script>

<script>
    function convertPDF() {

        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'letter');

        html2canvas(document.getElementById('chart1'), {
            //proxy: "https://html2canvas.appspot.com/query",
            //useCORS: true,
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

                pdf.addImage(canvas, 'JPEG', 15, 15);

                pdf.save('PDFTest.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/62d219a0fac54b94cd4f230e7bfc55aa3f8dcfa4/FileSaver.js"></script>

<script src="JSRefs/html2canvas_0.5.0-alpha1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain more on "not in IE11" ? You got an error and nothing happens ? if so, which error ? or you got an ugly pdf ? if so, can you share the OK PDF and the ugly one ?

Comment: Hi Ben, i am getting a blank PDF output in IE11(Only title appears in my IE11 output). For your reference added a screenshot of "PDF Outputs" link on my earlier posted question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sample, make a note of the listed important things in the code, which made the difference.

- gfxRenderer: "canvas"
- htmlLabels: false,

Below is the working code along with Tooltip functionality.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

        <script>
            dojoConfig = {
                parseOnLoad: true,      // enables declarative chart creation
                gfxRenderer: "canvas"   // canvas is first priority
            };
        </script>
        <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="html2canvas.js"></script>

        <script>
            function convertPDF() {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'letter');
                html2canvas(document.getElementById('chart1'), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        pdf.addImage(img, 'PNG', 15, 15);
                        pdf.save('PDFTest.pdf');
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            require([
                "dojox/charting/Chart",
                "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
                "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
                "dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedColumns",
                "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
                "dojox/charting/widget/SelectableLegend", 
                "dojox/gfx/utils",
                "dojo/ready",
                "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function (
                Chart, 
                Lines, 
                Default, 
                StackedColumns, 
                Tooltip, 
                SelectableLegend, 
                Utils,
                ready
            ) {
                var chart1 = new Chart("chart1");

                chart1.htmlLabels = false;
                chart1.title = "Stacked Chart";

                chart1.addPlot("stackedColumnsPlot", {
                   htmlLabels: false,
                   type: StackedColumns,
                   gap: 5,
                   lines: true,
                   areas: true,
                   markers: true,
                   labels: true,
                   labelOffset: -10,
                   labelStyle: "default",              
                   tension: "2"
                });

                chart1.addAxis("x", {
                   dropLabels: false,
                   labelSizeChange: true,
                   rotation: -20,
                   majorTicks: true,
                   majorTickStep: 1,
                   minorTicks: false,
                   font: "normal normal bold 12px Tahoma",
                   fontColor: "black",
                   labels: [
                       { "value": 1, "text": "A" }, 
                       { "value": 2, "text": "B" }, 
                       { "value": 3, "text": "C" }, 
                       { "value": 4, "text": "D" }, 
                       { "value": 5, "text": "E" }, 
                       { "value": 6, "text": "F" }
                   ]
                });

                chart1.addAxis("y", {
                   title: "Cost",
                   fixLower: "major",
                   fixUpper: "major",
                   includeZero: true,
                   majorTickStep: 500,
                   max: 1500,               
                   vertical: true
                });

                chart1.addSeries("AC", [300, 500, 500, 600, 300, 280], {
                    plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
                    stroke: {
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    fill: "#FFAEAE "
                });
                chart1.addSeries("TV", [244, 301, 699, 620, 820, 837], {
                   plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
                   stroke: {
                       color: "#FFFFFF"
                   },
                   fill: "#FFEC94"
                });
                chart1.addSeries("ACCE", [500, 100, 100, 100, 200, 250], {
                   plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
                   stroke: {
                       color: "#FFFFFF"
                   },
                   fill: "#B4D8E7"
                });
                chart1.addSeries("OTHER", [100, 150, 100, 700, 700, 80], {
                   plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
                   stroke: {
                       color: "#FFFFFF"
                   },
                   fill: "#56BAEC"
                });

                new Tooltip(chart1, "stackedColumnsPlot", {
                    text: function(chartItem) {
                        // console.debug(chartItem);
                        //return "Rating: " + chartItem.run.data[chartItem.index] + "; Total Value: " +   chartItem.y;
                        // return  "Comparision Rating: " + chartItem.y;
                       return "Value: " + chartItem.run.data[chartItem.index] + "; Stacked Value: "   + chartItem.y;
                    }
                });

                chart1.render();

                new SelectableLegend({
                   chart: chart1,
                   horizontal: true,
                   align: top
                }, "chart1SelectableLegend");          
           });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div id="chart1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

        <div id="chart1SelectableLegend"></div>

        <button id="pdfButton" onclick="convertPDF()">DownloadPDF</button>
    </body>
</html>
```